# Why should we use knockout utils over vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've been using Knockout for a while. It comes with a bunch of functions in `ko.utils`.

There are many built into JavaScript, like:

- `ko.utils.arrayMap = Array.prototype.map`
- `ko.utils.arrayFilter = Array.prototype.filter`

`ko.utils` functions take the array as the first argument, callback as the second but other than that they seem to work the same way.

I've searched on the topic and looked at the `ko.utils` declarations, and I can't see them doing anything special with an `observableArray`.

Do these functions only exist for compatability with ancient browsers?

Are there some functions I have missed that are knockout view model/observable specific?

Edit:
`unwrapObservable` is in `ko.utils` and is knockout specific and very handy.

Answer (score 2):

> Do these functions only exist for compatibility with ancient browsers?

Knockout came out in 2010, when "ancient" browsers were still heavily in use. [Browser support](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/browser-support.html) still includes Internet Explorer 6.